# Tradução dos motivos de rejeição de edições sugeridas

Tags: bug, status-pronto, internacionalização, filas-de-análise, edições-sugeridas

As opções oferecidas quando decidimos rejeitar uma sugestão de edição ainda não estão traduzidas:

[image: screenshot do diálogo]

#### Traduções sugeridas

- **plágio**
  A edição introduz conteúdo copiado de fonte externa sem a devida atribuição
- **edição inválida**
  A edição é incorreta, ou uma tentativa de debater ou comentar a postagem
- **alteração radical**
  A edição altera demais o original, acarretando em perda do sentido ou intenção original
- **insuficiente**
  A edição é insuficiente; sugestões de edição precisam melhorar significativamente a postagem, resolvendo os diversos problemas que ela apresentar
- **vandalismo**
  A edição introduz spam, desfigura a postagem ou é inadequada.

### UPDATE

As descrições agora estão traduzidas, mas os nomes dos motivos, não:
[EN: Now I see the descriptions translated, but the option title are still in English]:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sugestão para o "wiki not helpful"
[EN: Suggestion for "wiki not helpful"]

- **o wiki não é útil**
  A edição não obedece às [diretrizes para wikis de tag][guidelines], e é improvável que ajude a instruir futuros visitantes quanto ao uso correto da tag.

Answer (score 4):

Added translations, they'll be available in build rev `2014.3.14.1462`.

Comment: The descriptions are now translated, but not the option titles. Please see my update above.

Comment: @bfavaretto adding overrides for those too. got any suggestions for the `wiki not helpful` part?

Comment: I added a suggestion at the end of the question.