# Como determinar se uma edição sugerida é insuficiente ("too minor")?

Tags: debate, filas-de-análise, edições-sugeridas

Eu reviso muitas edições sugeridas, e por vezes tenho dúvidas se devo rejeitar uma edição como insuficiente (*too minor*). A mesma dúvida se aplica a melhorar a edição e desmarcar o checkbox de "edição útil". A descrição do motivo de rejeição ([ainda em inglês](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1061)) diz:

> This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post.

No SO em inglês, a orientação é ser rigoroso com isso: se a edição não resolve todos ou quase todos os problemas do post, rejeite como *too minor*. Aqui, porém, adotei uma postura um pouco mais branda desde o beta privado: tenho rejeitado por esse motivo somente edições que deixam passar coisas muito gritantes, e/ou se considero que a edição não contribui praticamente nada.

Há casos mais nebulosos. Por exemplo, a sugestão acrescenta uma tag (bom!), mas não resolve problemas de formatação (oh não!). [Aqui, por exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5997).

Como proceder nesses casos? Vocês acham que está na hora de sermos mais rigorosos com as edições sugeridas?

Comment: Se a intenção é treinar bons editores, **sim**, edições minúsculas ou que somente adicionam tags irrelevantes devem ser rejeitadas.

Comment: Minha maior cisma é com o limite de caracteres para uma edição. Ontem eu editei uma resposta onde apenas dois caracteres estavam errados - porém exatamente no nome das funções chamadas. Eram erros críticos, mas eu tive que editar algumas marcadores de formatação duplicados apenas para que o este fosse considerado válido.

Comment: @OnoSendai Acho importante o limite. É um mínimo de garantia contra edições ridículas, embora cause os problemas que você relatou em casos em que uma micro-edição seria legítima. Mas como você viu, tem várias maneiras de contornar.

Comment: @brasofilo O objetivo principal é melhorar o conteúdo do site. Nos primeiros dois meses (beta privado), quase qualquer coisa era lucro (por exemplo, mesmo um tag wiki mais-ou-menos era melhor que nenhum). Atualmente, um pouco menos, mas não sei se devemos ser tão rigorosos quanto no SO. Se a edição for boa (não irrelevante!), mas incompleta, será que devemos rejeitar? O problema dos robo-reviewers do SO ainda não existe aqui (pelo menos não com tanta gravidade).

Comment: Como fica o caso de pequenos erros de digitação? Pode ser um problema "irrelevante" no sentido de que todos podem ver que a pessoa apenas comeu uma letra, mas eu (e talvez muitos outros) particularmente fico extremamente incomodado de ver uma palavra errada e não poder deixá-la certa se está a meu alcance fazê-lo. hehe..

Comment: @Claudio Devido à exigência do comprimento mínimo de edição, muitas vezes você só conseguirá sugerir edições assim se burlar o sistema de alguma maneira. Mas após atingir certo nível de reputação, suas edições não precisam mais ser aprovadas. Aí você fica livre para corrigir essas coisas à vontade (eu faço muito isso).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A orientação do SO funciona lá porque há uma comunidade muito grande que *entende* como as coisas devem funcionar, e os benefícios delas funcionarem dessa maneira. Eu não acho que nós estamos nesse ponto. Aplicar um filtro restritivo como esse hoje serviria muito mais para desincentivar uma comunidade que ainda está aprendendo a tomar conta do próprio site, do que mitigaria algum problema causado por excesso de edições.

Vide nossa fila de análise que está praticamente sempre vazia (o que é muito, muito sensacional e os revisores estão de parabéns.)

Para um usuário novo existem diversas "barreiras" mentais que devem ser transpostas até ele compreender que a edição é um direito real dele. Ter a primeira edição aceita é uma experiência que deve incentivá-lo a buscar mais e mais. Também faz parte da gamificação do site. Causar rejeições em série seria detrimental à esse propósito.

Questões relacionadas à revisão de edições são sempre escabrosas, porque não faltam contra-exemplos para qualquer afirmação que se faça. Mas eu acho que ser mais leniente valha a pena. O **pior** que pode acontecer é um post melhorar, mas não muito. Melhor que manter o post como está na esperança de que alguém vai aparecer e acertar tudo.

A regra do SO é restrita porque o contexto é diferente. Nós não temos o volume deles e nem tantos casos de gente querendo ganhar um monte de reputação por conta das edições. Então não acho que valha a pena aumentar o rigor ainda.

Comment: Concordo. Podemos ser um pouco lenientes principalmente com as edições "insuficientes" (minha sugestão de tradução para *too minor*). Mas por enquanto esse motivo está muito sujeito à opinião de cada um sobre o que seria "suficiente". Vai levar um tempo até formarmos uma cultura mais consistente.