# Revisões ínfimas ou até inexistentes

Tags: debate, moderação

Como evitar ou sinalizar revisões inexistentes como [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/11594/revisions)?

[image: usando]

Na imagem acima, o moderador alterou usando para... usando?
Até alterar [apenas uma tag](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1062/como-determinar-se-uma-edicao-sugerida-e-insuficiente-too-minor), embora eu não concorde, vá lá, mas acredito que tudo tenha limite.

Como proceder em situações como esta?

Procurei casos semelhantes no meta, porém não encontrei. Caso hajam

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Na verdade, a palavra estava duplicada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Realmente pareceu estranho. Existe um mínimo em cada campo de edição. Obrigado!